# stackoverflow appears without CSS in Chrome

Tags: support, bug

When viewing the main stackoverflow.com site in Chrome 28, I don't get the CSS.

[image: stackoverflow without CSS]

It works fine in IE10.

The chrome debugger shows a failure to get CSS resources over the HTTPS connection:

```
GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=7f92ff1ddd7d  stackoverflow.com/:10
GET https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=dd6898efd655  stackoverflow.com/:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:16
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:23
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:30
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:35
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:3079
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:3092
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined stackoverflow.com/:3105
allow right click initializing for http://stackoverflow.com/ rightclick.js:1
allow right click processing http://stackoverflow.com/
```

On stackexchange sites where the CSS resources are retrieved over an HTTP connection, there are no errors.

I note that if I try to directly go to https://sstatic.net, chrome gives me a warning about the certificate's domain not matching *.stackexchange.com.

If it matters, I am behind an iPrism web filter.